# html/php/sql form with insert/update

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a table that has a list of clients on a waiting list where you can select to move one of them into a vacant room.

When you select this client, it moves onto a page called 'MoveIn1.html' where it gets that client's ID and uses it to display his/her name and ID. It also displays a drop-down box showing all the rooms that are vacant, giving the user a choice of which room to move the client into. The user then also chooses the date the client will move in and submits this information.

After it is submitted, it goes onto 'MoveIn2.php' where it **should** update the client's active to '1' (aka, yes), update the selected room's room_vacant to '0' (aka, no) and create/insert into a new occupancy record, along with the client's id (occupancy_client_id), the room id (occupancy_room_id) and the start date. I don't get a single error but my tables do not get updated and no occupancy record is created; when echo'ing my carried variables nothing is displayed either so I'm not sure how to sort this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Some of MoveIn1.html code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
//SELECTS from client where the selected client's ID is equal to client_id
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

echo "<b>Client ID: </b>" . $row['client_id'];
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<b>Client Name: </b>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
echo "<br><br>";


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Creates a form for room_id
echo "<form action='MoveIn2.php'>";
//Creates drop down box to show the current rooms vacant

echo "<b>Choose a room: </b>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM room";
$sql.= " WHERE room_vacant = 1";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
echo "<select name='room_id'>";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['room_id'] . "'>" . $row['room_id'] . "</option>";
} //Closes drop down box
echo "</select><br><br>";

//Move-in date
echo "<b>Move-in date: </b>";
echo "<input type='date' name='start_date' value='" . date("Y/m/d") . "' required/><br><br>";


echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id .  "'/>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='submit' value='submit' />";

//Submit button
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'><br><br>";
echo "<input type='button' name='cancel' value='Cancel' onclick='window.location='ViewWaitingList.html'' /><br><br>";

//Closes form
echo "</form>";
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

?>
```

Some of MoveIn2.php code:

```
<?php
require("dbconnect.php");

//CLIENT
$id = $_POST['id'];
//UPDATES client's to 1/Yes to say that they're now an active client in JRH, 
//where the selected client's ID is equal to :id
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE client SET active = 1 WHERE client_id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

//ROOM
$room_id = $_POST['room_id'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE room SET room_vacant = 0 WHERE room_id = :room_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':room_id', $room_id);
$stmt->execute();

//OCCUPANCY
$id = $_POST['id'];
$room_id = $_POST['room_id'];
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO occupancy (occupancy_client_id, occupancy_room_id, start_date) VALUES(:id, :room_id, :start_date)");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':room_id', $room_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':start_date', $start_date);
$stmt->execute();

echo $id;
echo $room_id;
echo $start_date;


?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised that you're not seeing errors: you're not looking for them. Check your calls to MySQL

Comment: I take it that you've instructed Apache to treat `MoveIn1.html` to run as PHP? If not, you'll need to rename it to `MoveIn1.php`, otherwise that code won't run.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I've looked, nothing comes up

Comment: @Fred-ii- yo fred, all the php stuff in MoveIn1.html is within php tags within html tags/file but I just took a little snippet of the code and put it here

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Have you instructed Apache to treat `.html` as PHP? That's the first thing I need to know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I have bud, I've got loads of php within html and it works fine

Comment: OK. Let's start with some simple debugging techniques, if you're not doing so already. Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, then add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also `var_dump();` to see what's going through or not.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that you're using `echo "<form action='MoveIn2.php'>";` - Without explicitly stating that it should be a POST method and you're trying to pass POST arrays in the next page, forms default to GET, which in turn will fail *silently*. You could try changing all `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` to see if that makes a difference, if you don't want to specify a POST method in the form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have a lot of 'undefined index error's for id, room_id and start_date, so I'm assuming these variables aren't being carried over to the MoveIn2.php page from the MoveIn1.html page?? (as you can tell I'm still learning)

Comment: There you go. Try changing `echo "<form action='MoveIn2.php'>";` to `echo "<form action='MoveIn2.php' method='post'>";` see what that gives.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yay it works!! Thanks again Fred :) (post it as an answer so I can tick it), thanks for kinda following my questions by the way, I'm sure I'll have some more on the way haha ;)

Comment: You're welcome Jack. I'm glad it worked out, *cheers!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've had to add something to this (for another table) and nothings working for that either lol so I might need some help

Comment: @Jack You may need to post a new question Jack. Let me know if you do and I'll have a look at it. Leave me the link.

Comment: @Fred-ii- working on it now

Comment: @Fred-ii- Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816264/html-php-mysql-insert-not-working

Comment: Glad to see it was resolved. Couldn't get to it on time; was eating lunch. *Cheers!* - ah, the little things eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using echo `"<form action='MoveIn2.php'>";`  without explicitly stating that it should be a POST method and you're trying to pass POST arrays in the next page, forms default to GET, which in turn will fail *silently.*

Change:

```
echo "<form action='MoveIn2.php'>";
```

to

```
echo "<form action='MoveIn2.php' method='post'>";
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thanks again Fred! Can't believe how much of an idiot I was, too many times my code has failed due to silly mistakes such as this.

Comment: @Jack You're quite welcome Jack. I've been down that road also, so I'm passing on the help. We all have to start *somewhere*. Cheers ;-)

Comment: Exactly, I'm (hopefully) going to be studying computer science at university in September and I can't wait