# HTML form insert not working in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

This follows on from a previous question ([html/php/sql form with insert/update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794702/html-php-sql-form-with-insert-update?noredirect=1#comment45903676_28794702)) so use that for reference on the HTML form. When a client moves in, their client's active is changed to 1, the room's room_vacant is changed to 0, and an occupancy record is made.

As well as this, the first rental payment needs to be generated using all this information. The rent_occupancy_id is worked out through the user of `lastInsertId()`, as the last inserted id would've been the occupancy ID.

The rent_cost is generated whether the client moving in is on benefits on not. If a client is not on benefits, then the rent_cost = £126.57 but if they are then rent_cost = £20.03. The `date_lastpaid` is the same as the start_date of the client's occupancy record and the date_due is equal to a week ahead of the `date_lastpaid`.

The problem is that a rent record is not being created yet all the other changes for the other records etc. are being made. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
require("dbconnect.php");

//CLIENT
$id = $_POST['id'];
//UPDATES client's to 1/Yes to say that they're now an active client in JRH, 
//where the selected client's ID is equal to :id
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE client SET active = 1 WHERE client_id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

//ROOM
$room_id = $_POST['room_id'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE room SET room_vacant = 0 WHERE room_id = :room_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':room_id', $room_id);
$stmt->execute();

//OCCUPANCY
$id = $_POST['id'];
$room_id = $_POST['room_id'];
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO occupancy (occupancy_client_id, occupancy_room_id, start_date) VALUES(:id, :room_id, :start_date)");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':room_id', $room_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':start_date', $start_date);
$stmt->execute();

//Working out Rent Cost
$id = $_POST['id'];
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
//Works out whether a client has benefits or not,
//and then uses this information to generate a cost of the rent
if ($row['benefits'] == '0') {
$rent_cost = "126.57";
} else{
$rent_cost = "20.03";
}


//RENT INSERT
//
//As the occupancy record is being created above
//and the rent table needs a rent_occupancy_id to join,
//then we use lastInsertId() in order to get that occupancy id
$rent_occupancy_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$date_lastpaid = $_POST['start_date']; //As the client hasn't made a payment yet,
//we say that their last payment was the date they joined
$date_due = strtotime($date_lastpaid);
$date_due = strtotime('+1 week', $date_due);
$date_due = date('Y/m/d', $date_due);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO rent (rent_occupancy_id, rent_cost, date_lastpaid, date_due) VALUES (:rent_occupancy_id, :rent_cost, :date_lastpaid, :date_due)");
$stmt->BindParam(':rent_occupancy_id', $rent_occupancy_id);
$stmt->BindParam(':rent_cost', $rent_cost);
$stmt->BindParam(':date_lastpaid', $date_lastpaid);
$stmt->BindParam(':date_due', $date_due);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change to lowercase first letter in `bindParam()`;

```
$stmt->bindParam(':rent_occupancy_id', $rent_occupancy_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':rent_cost', $rent_cost);
$stmt->bindParam(':date_lastpaid', $date_lastpaid);
$stmt->bindParam(':date_due', $date_due);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: wow hahaha, I'm such an idiot. I love programming cos of funny stuff like this. I'll confirm you answer once it lets me

Comment: :-) sometimes it happen :-)

Comment: *Hm....* that is indeed strange. I really don't want the one to be the party pooper here (lol), but in my own tests, both `bindParam` and `BindParam` did in fact work. I did find an article on this http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/2tue8i/a_little_help_with_pdo_prepare_and_bindparam/ and states that it shouldn't matter, but could be an issue. This is something that isn't documented enough and the guys at PHP.net should be informed of it. Just a sidenote to let y'all know. By the way, I am not contesting the answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know Fred it's weird isn't it?? But this seemed to work for me haha, it can be so weird sometimes

Comment: @Jack I'm going to pursue this a bit further to find out why that is. There might be something in your setup that doesn't allow it; some type of exceptions restriction; *most bizarre*. Functions/classes shouldn't be case-sensitive, as opposed to variables; that's what I don't get. I might post it on meta and/or db exchange on Stack.